# Add optional authentication steps after FORM_LOGIN_FILTER in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have a basic login workflow with Spring Security in a Web application: The user logs in via a form which is eventually handled by the application logic in a `UserDetailsService` called from the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with a token created by the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

However, in some cases (decided at runtime via a user preference), I'd like to have an additional authentication step after that (basically two factor authentication). I tried adding another filter like so

```
<custom-filter ref="twoFactorAuthFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
```

but this filter is never invoked if form login succeeds. My plan was to create a special `TwoFactorAuthenticationToken` that can be accepted by a `TwoFactorAuthenticationProvider` but as the filter is not invoked, my new authentication provider isn't either. I want the whole security chain to abort if the login credentials are wrong but continue traversing it if they are correct and continue to the (optional) next step.

Is it possible to do it how I want without rewriting the the existing `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`? I feel like this must be quite easy because Spring usually is pretty extensible but I have been fighting with this for many days now and have not yet had any success.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to have two filters: one for `userNamePasswordFilter` and one for your `tokenFilter`. In case your user has two-factor auth enabled, your `userDetailsService` for `daoAuthenticationProvider` should grant him only an instance of `SimpleGrantedAuthority` with a role "ROLE_PRE_AUTH" for example. The access to `tokenFilter` should be provided only to users with this role - "ROLE_PRE_AUTH" and that filter should attempt authentication on your secondary token and proceed to grant the user his actual authorities (USER, ADMIN, etc) from `tokenProvider`. 
The way to display that additional pop-up form is, again, to check if the user's role is "ROLE_PRE_AUTH".

Comment: This is actually pretty close to what I ended up doing. The decision whether to show the additional dialog is done in a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. It's still pretty fiddly I think. A lot of components need to be aware of the two factor authentication and I wasn't able to cleanly factor it out.

Comment: I reuse the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` from the `daoAuthenticationProvider` with an `ajaxSuccess` controller endpoint that issues a 201 in case a PIN token is created. The frontend callback can then react to this response status with appropriate changes to the login form.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extend `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and override `additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)` with your after login authentication logic.

```
public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    public additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);

        // Your Logic Here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

May be I misunderstood your problem because you mentioned "Logic". Anyway this [post](http://altfatterz.blogspot.com/2014/02/two-factor-authentication-with-spring.html) shows a elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: How would I display an additional form that way? I think it's already too late when I'm in the authentication provider and has to be done at the filter level. But I'm not sure...